# SQL Show one table with a foreing key from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display on SQL a table where the 1st table still the same but with the 2nd table the foreign key of this table will help to no show the foreign key on the fist table.
Here's my tables,

**Table Login**

```
ID(foreign key), Username,Password,Level
-----------------------------------------
1,               test,    test,    Client
7,               ClientU, ClientP, Client
```

**Table Friends**

```
ID_User,ID_Friends
------------------
7,      1
```

My request is like when I put on a jsp page a table to no have the possibilities to add the same user again and over. Is it possible with an SQL command to display 0 lines if Login.ID = Friends.ID_User are equals that they don't show up. It will help on my JSP page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Login 
INNER JOIN Friends ON Login.id != Friends.id_user AND Login.id != Friends.id_friend;
```

But I'm afraid if I add one more friends that others Users can't have this friend because it will not show up on the JSP table to add a friend because someone else will have this friend...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).